# Date time difference in mysql shows incorrect result

Tags: mysql

```
select CONCAT(
    Lpad(
        FLOOR(HOUR(TIMEDIFF('2015-06-25 12:10', '2011-06-21 10:10')) / 24),
        4,0),':',
    Lpad(
        MOD(HOUR(TIMEDIFF('2014-06-25 12:10', '2015-06-21 10:10')), 24),
        4,0),':',
    Lpad(
        MINUTE(TIMEDIFF('2014-06-25 12:10', '2015-06-21 10:15')),
        4,0), '')
```

The above MySQL select statement gives

> incorrect report.Required format of date  = days:hours:minutes

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

The functions you are using are limited by the *TIME* type that may range from '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'. you should use `TIMESTAMPDIFF`  which return integers.

```
select
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,'2011-06-21 10:10','2015-06-25 12:10') as c_days,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,'2014-06-25 12:10', '2015-06-21 10:10') as c_hrs,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'2014-06-25 12:10', '2015-06-21 10:15') as c_mnt;
```

but this doesn't make much sense you've probably have some typos in your formula, the code bellow is probably what you're looking for.

```
set @a_mnt := TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'2014-06-25 12:10', '2015-06-21 10:10');
select
    concat(
        lpad(floor(@a_mnt := @a_mnt / 1440 ), 4, 0), ':',
        lpad(floor(@a_mnt := ((@a_mnt - floor(@a_mnt)) * 24)), 4, 0), ':',
        lpad(floor((@a_mnt - floor(@a_mnt)) * 60 ), 4, 0)) as result;
```